# If all eigenvalues are < 1, fixed point iterations converges to the only solution

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, fixed-point-iteration

Theorem states that for every initial value fixed point iteration x = Bx+b converges to the only solution of the system if all $|\lambda| $ < 1. Prove it using Jordans normal form. Initial form is Ax=b and to get B from A us whatever you want(Althoug nothing is known about A). Only thing is that if all eigenvalues of B are less than 1 then there is only 1 solution and fixed point iteration will find it.

1. How can I represent the matrix B using Jordans normal form?
2. What does Jordans normal form say about eigenvalues?
3. Is there anything else i need to know to prove this?

I understand that Jordan normal form consists of Jordan boxes where diagonal has eigenvalue and diagonal on top has 1-s. But what determines the Jordans box size?

Comment: What exactly is your linear system? The iteration, thus $(I-B) x = b$, or something else?

Comment: Initial form is Ax = b